# Convert SQL to LINQ equivalent

Tags: c#, sql, linq

i have trouble with converting this syntax to Linq:

```
SELECT 
    Medlemmer.Skif, 
    Grader.Grad, 
    Medlemmer.Navn, 
    Medlemmer.Mellemnavn, 
    Medlemmer.Efternavn, 
    Medlemmer.Adresse, 
    Medlemmer.Telefon, 
    Medlemmer.Mobil, 
    Medlemmer.PostNr, 
    Medlemmer.town, 
    Medlemmer.mail, 
    Medlemmer.Picture 
FROM 
    Medlemmer 
    CROSS APPLY Get_grader(Medlemmer.Skif) as Grader 
WHERE 
    Medlemmer.Aktiv = 1
ORDER BY 
    Medlemmer.Navn
```

Get_grader() is function that returns a table with data)

I am here:

```
var q = from a in db.GetTable<Medlemmer>()
           where a.Aktiv == true
           orderby a.Navn
           select new
               {
                 Grad = db.Get_grader(Convert.ToInt32(a.Skif)),
                 Skif = a.Skif,
                 Navn = a.Navn,
                 Mellemnavn = a.Mellemnavn,
                 Efternavn = a.Efternavn,
                 Adresse = a.Adresse,
                 Telefon = a.Telefon,
                 Mobil = a.Mobil,
                 PostNr = a.PostNr,
                 town = a.town,
                 mail = a.mail,
                 Picture = a.Picture 
               };
```

Right now the Grad returns "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Get_grader]"

How do I get the correct value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to test, but try this:

```
var q = from a in db.GetTable<Medlemmer>()
        from g in db.Get_grader(Convert.ToInt32(a.Skif))
           where a.Aktiv == true
           orderby a.Navn
           select new
               {
                 Grad = g.Grad,
                 Skif = a.Skif,
                 Navn = a.Navn,
                 Mellemnavn = a.Mellemnavn,
                 Efternavn = a.Efternavn,
                 Adresse = a.Adresse,
                 Telefon = a.Telefon,
                 Mobil = a.Mobil,
                 PostNr = a.PostNr,
                 town = a.town,
                 mail = a.mail,
                 Picture = a.Picture 
               };
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
var q = from a in db.GetTable<Medlemmer>()
            from grad in db.Get_grader(Convert.ToInt32(a.Skif))
           where a.Aktiv == true
           orderby a.Navn
           select new
               {
                 Skif = a.Skif,
                 Grad =grad.Grad
                 Navn = a.Navn,
                 Mellemnavn = a.Mellemnavn,
                 Efternavn = a.Efternavn,
                 Adresse = a.Adresse,
                 Telefon = a.Telefon,
                 Mobil = a.Mobil,
                 PostNr = a.PostNr,
                 town = a.town,
                 mail = a.mail,
                 Picture = a.Picture 
               };
```

Or if you want a list of just grader. Then something like this maybe:

```
var q = from a in db.GetTable<Medlemmer>()
           where a.Aktiv == true
           orderby a.Navn
           select new
               {
                 Skif = a.Skif,
                 Grad = db.Get_grader(Convert.ToInt32(a.Skif))
                                       .Select(s=>s.Grad),
                 Navn = a.Navn,
                 Mellemnavn = a.Mellemnavn,
                 Efternavn = a.Efternavn,
                 Adresse = a.Adresse,
                 Telefon = a.Telefon,
                 Mobil = a.Mobil,
                 PostNr = a.PostNr,
                 town = a.town,
                 mail = a.mail,
                 Picture = a.Picture 
               };
```